# adjust values which are associated with a string from a different column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which I'd like to adjust the values which are associated with a string from a different column. Example, all values in column 'wgt' that is associated with 'joe' in the 'name' column to multiply 1.10.

original df

| name | wgt |
| --- | --- |
| joe | 10 |
| gary | 8 |
| pete | 12 |
| pete | 13 |
| pete | 14 |
| joe | 11 |
| gary | 7 |
| gary | 5 |
| gary | 7 |

adjusted df

| name | wgt |
| --- | --- |
| joe | 11 |
| gary | 8 |
| pete | 12 |
| pete | 13 |
| pete | 14 |
| joe | 12.1 |
| gary | 7 |
| gary | 5 |
| gary | 7 |

code for sample df

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'name':['joe','gary','pete','pete','pete','joe','gary','gary','gary'
],'wgt':[10,8,12,13,14,11,7,5,7,]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df['wgt'] = np.where(df.name == "joe", df.wgt * 1.1, df.wgt)
```

or

```
df.loc[df.name == "joe", "wgt"] *= 1.1
```